# Can you use the programs you "pip install" in the Command-line?

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

As a Python beginner, I was downloading the OpenAI's [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper#setup) with the following command: `pip install -U openai-whisper`, and noticed that you can use Whisper in both [Python](https://github.com/openai/whisper#python-usage) and the [Command-line](https://github.com/openai/whisper#command-line-usage).

To my knowledge, `pip install` installs Python packages, so should only be available within Python, but it seems like you can use Whisper in the command line?

In summary, why does `pip install`-ing Python packages let you use the package in the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you install something with `pip`, if the package defines an entry point, it creates a command-line wrapper, and adds it to your Python installation's bin. Your PATH environment variable should include the folder Python's bin, so you can run the package from the command-line.

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/

Comment: Well said! And the salient point here is that *not all Python packages come with a CLI* - it's something that has to be implemented by the developers of the library in question.

Answer (score 2):

`pip` installs Python *distribution packages*, which can contain both *import packages* and standalone scripts. (The term "package" is, unfortunately, heavily overloaded.)